# select - How to change the color of the selected option background?

Tags: css

Note: the question is not about how to change the bg color of the selected option.

When I open a select dropdown, the current selected option has a different color, when I hover with the mouse this color jump to other option that I hover on

[image]

Is there a way to change the bg color of the current hover option?

Note: adding `background-color: white;` in `hover` state doesn't seems have an effect.

See the current css

[image]

and in hover state
[image]

Comment: Your assumption of changing the background on a `:hover` state is correct. The reason you're experiencing why it doesn't work, is because the style gets overwritten further down the CSS tree. Try to either find where that happens and tweak the order of CSS, or try and add the `!important` property.

Comment: Example: `[selector]:hover { background-color: white !important; 0 }`.

Comment: i tried this once.

Comment: Martin, see the attached image, you can see that the hover state is checked, and the background is not strike through, which means it is not overiden

Answer (score 1):

[image]

If you mean the color `BLUE HIGHLIGHT`, well, it cant be change by CSS. 
Because it is from the browser. you can either use `libraries` or `ul>li`

Please see below, what you atleast can do.
I hope this will help you.

```css
select option:checked {
    background: yellow;
    color: green;
}
```

```html
<select>
  <option>
    I wanted to be happy
  </option>
  <option>
    I wanted money
  </option>
  <option>
    I wanted money
  </option>
  <option>
    I wanted money
  </option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an alternative idea with js. May be it could be helpful.

```js
function classToSelectedOption() {
  var alreadySelected = document.querySelectorAll(".selected");
  //Remove class to previus selected option
  [].forEach.call(alreadySelected, function(el) {
      el.classList.remove("selected");
  });
  
  //Add class to current selected option
  var value = document.getElementById("select").value;
  document.querySelector('option[ value=' + value + ']').classList.add("selected");
  
}
```

```css
select option {
  background: black;
  color: #fff;
}

select option.selected {
  background: red !important;
}
```

```html
<select id="select" onchange="classToSelectedOption()">
  <option value="first">first</option>
  <option value="second">second</option>
  <option value="third">third</option>
  <option value="fourth">fourth</option>
</select>
```